# read subprocess output multi-byte characters one by one

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, subprocess, decode

I'm running a process using subprocess:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What I want to do is to read the output characters one by one in a loop:

```
while something:
    char = p.stdout.read(1)
```

In python3 `subprocess.Popen().stdout.read()` returns `bytes()` not `str()`. I want to use it as str so I have to do:

```
    char = char.decode("utf-8")
```

and it works fine with ascii characters.

But with non-ascii characters (eg. greek letters) I get a UnicodeDecodeError. That's why greek chars are consisted of more than one bytes. Here's the problem:

```
>>> b'\xce\xb5'.decode('utf-8')
'ε'
>>> b'\xce'.decode('utf-8') # b'\xce' is what subprocess...read(1) returns - one byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: unexpected end of data
>>>
```

How can I deal with this?
The output of `subprocess.Popen().stdout.read()` (as a string) can be something like "lorem ipsum εφδφδσloremipsum".

I want to read one character a time but this character can consisted of multiple bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the file object in [`io.TextIOWrapper()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to decode the pipe on the fly:

```
import io

reader = io.TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding='utf8')
while something:
    char = reader.read(1)
```